# It seems I deleted (completely) the default repository for Artful, how do I get it back?

Tags: lubuntu, repository, 17.10

I don't know how it happened but somehow it was deleted.  Is it gone for good or can I possibly re-add the default repo that comes with 17.10?  It doesn't even seem to show up in the software & updates channel as disabled. 
 Thanks and regards,
Thomas

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply open software and updates and re-set your choices in the first tab, select a server from dropdown. You should get a requeast for putting in your password during doing that. (see screen-shot)

[image]

This should usually fix it.

---

alternatively you can  use `sudo -i` in terminal and copy & paste the following (complete block) into it:

```
cat > /etc/apt/sources.list << EOF
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu artful main restricted universe multiverse
deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu artful main restricted universe multiverse
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu artful-updates main restricted universe multiverse
deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu artful-updates main restricted universe multiverse
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu artful-backports main restricted universe multiverse
deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu artful-backports main restricted universe multiverse
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu artful-security main restricted universe multiverse
deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu artful-security main restricted universe multiverse
#deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu artful-proposed restricted main universe multiverse
#deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu artful-proposed restricted main universe multiverse
deb http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu artful partner
deb-src http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu artful partner
EOF
```

After that you should use `exit` to get out of root. This should fix it as well.

Comment: Interesting!  I really thought I would have to add a repo using the sudo add repository command.  Guess not!  Thanks!

Comment: Actually it only seemed to work temporarily.  I could continue to do this, but it probably wont solve much.

Comment: This sounds as if something else is going wrong there, settings made don't simply revert themselves. You can find me most of the time in general [chat].